# Printing out Hashtable without using a loop in c#

Tags: c#, hashtable, trace

I need to print out in a file a `HashTable`.

Is it possible to do it without a `for`/`foreach` loop? Something like:

```
 Hashtable myHash;

 Logging.traceMessage(Datetime.now, myhash) // I want to have just a single datatime entry in my traceMessage.
```

My expected output is something like:

> 'hashtable'
>
> [KEY] - [VALUE]
>
> pizzas - one
>
> costumer - three
>
> 'TraceFile'
>
> Datetime: pizzas - one , costumer - three

If I use a foreach loop for printing out the hash I will get a datetime in every key and value pair.

Comment: You almost certainly should not be using `HashTable` these days; use `Dictionary` instead so that you can leverage generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following.  It should be fairly optimized for your needs.

```
Hashtable mhash = new Hashtable();

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var myhash in mhash)
{
    sb.AppendLine(myhash.ToString()); -- Note you format your hash however you want here
}

Logging.traceMessage(DateTime.Now, sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate in the list at some point - but for your purpose, the below extension method may help

Define your Extension method in a library (lets say myExtensions)

```
public static string EntriesCSV(this Hashtable ht) 
{
string ls_return; 
foreach (var pair in ht)
ls_return += String.Format("{0}={1};\r\n", pair.Key, pair.Value); //this is very simple statement, but you can improve this to fit your needs
return ls_return;

}
```

Reference your extensions library

```
using myExtensions;
```

Enjoy simplicity code :)

```
Hashtable myHash;
Logging.traceMessage(Datetime.now, myhash.EntriesCSV());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: String concatenation over a large loop like this is highly inefficient.

Comment: @Servy: true - +1; however the concept is there and the OP can use StringBuilder in case the hashtable is large or alternate lists

Comment: +1 I like this solution too - except I would definitely replace with StringBuilder.